# To prove a proposition about Taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f \in C^0[a, b]$ and that $f'$ exists and is bounded by $M$ on $(a, b)$. Given $c \in [a, b]$, for all $x \in [a, b]$, we have
$$|f(x) − p_0(x)| ≤ M|x − c|$$ , where $p_0(x)$ is the first term of Taylor polynomial.

Can I say $p_0(x) = f(c)$ here? I sort of don't know how to start this proof.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We if $f \in C^1$, we'd have
$$ f(x) =  f(x_0) + f'(\xi(x)) (x-x_0) $$
via Mean Value Theorem ( with $x_0$ in the interval ). We have that $f \in C^0$, and we're given that $|f' | \leq M$ everywhere in the interval. This gives us a bound on the error terms, looking at the above, show we have
 $$|f(x) - f(x_0) | \leq M | x-x_0| $$
Clearly if we take the limit as $x \to x_0$, we have that
 $$\lim_{x \to x_0 }  |f(x) - f(x_0) |= 0 \implies \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0) $$

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to use Taylor's Thm here since we actually want to prove Taylor's Thm by this proposition. Do we have other ways to prove this?

Comment: Do you have the mean value theorem? This will give the above form as well.